# Vectors in three-dimensional space: locus of a variable point

Tags: geometry, vectors, locus

The fixed point B has position vector **$b$** relative to a fixed point $O$. A variable point $M$ has position vector **$m$** relative to $O$. Find the locus of M if **m $\cdot$ (m – b)=0**.

I am told the answer is derived as such:
[image]
Can somebody explain the solution to me? I've tried but can't seem to understand...thanks!

Comment: It looks very clear. What is the "imply" you do not understand ?

Comment: I don't understand how we get from the second statement to "Angle OMB = 90 degrees". And then after that, how do I obtain a sphere?

Comment: 1) A dot product of two vectors equal to 0 means orthogonality of these vectors, whence the 90° angle. Then 2) If you where in 2D, the set of points from which you see a line segment OB under an angle of 90° is a circle with diameter OB. Now rotate this circle in 3D space, you get a sphere.

Answer (score 1):

If $O$ and $B$ are two antipodal points on a circle in the plane, and $M$ is another point on the circle, then $\angle OMB = 90^\circ$.  In 3-D space, the locus of all such points will be obtained by rotating this circle around the line $OB$, obtaining a sphere.

As an aside, note that you can also solve this problem by completing the square:
\begin{align*}
\vec{m} \cdot \vec{m} - \vec{m} \cdot \vec{b} &= 0 \\
\vec{m} \cdot \vec{m} - \vec{m} \cdot \vec{b} + \frac{1}{4} \vec{b}\cdot \vec{b} &= \frac{1}{4} |\vec{b}|^2 \\
\left( \vec{m} - \frac{1}{2} \vec{b} \right) \cdot \left( \vec{m} - \frac{1}{2} \vec{b} \right) &=  \frac{1}{4} \left| \vec{b} \right|^2 \\
\left| \vec{m} - \frac{1}{2} \vec{b} \right| = \frac{1}{2} \left| \vec{b} \right| 
\end{align*}
In other words, the set of all points that satisfy this equation form a sphere of radius $\frac{1}{2} |\vec{b}|$, centered at the location $\frac{1}{2} \vec{b}$.  This is, of course, equivalent to the answer in the solution you were given.

Answer (score 0):

If $\vec{OM}=(x,y,z)$ and $\vec{OB}=(a,b,c)$ then

$$\vec{OM}.\vec{BM}=0\implies$$

$$x(x-a)+y(y-b)+z(z-c)=0 \implies$$

$$(x-\frac{a}{2})^2+(y-\frac{b}{2})^2+(z-\frac{c}{2})^2=\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{4}$$

the point M is in the sphere of center $(\frac{a}{2},\frac{b}{2},\frac{c}{2})$ and radius

$R=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}{2}$.